# How to Compare 2 Character Arrays

Tags: c

How do I compare these two character arrays to make sure they are identical?

```
char test[10] = "idrinkcoke"
char test2[10] = "idrinknote"
```

I'm thinking of using `for loop`, but I read somewhere else that I couldnt do `test[i] == test2[i]` in C.

I would really appreciate if someone could help this. Thank you.

Comment: `strcmp(a, b) == 0` is what you are looking for.

Comment: You can do `test[i] == test2[i]`, since they are character comparisons. but to compare string, you need to use the function `strcmp()`

Comment: so in my case `strcmp(test[i],test2[i])` ?

Comment: @ThomasWest, No, `strcmp(test, test2) `

Comment: `I read somewhere else that I couldnt do test[i] == test2[i] in C` - Where did you read this?

Comment: @AlejandroMorán sorry, I dont know about this.

Comment: @KeineLust thank you!

Comment: Use strncmp, avoid using strcmp. Aside of that - you are overflowing the memory here - you allocated 10 characters and you wrote 11 (10 characters from "idrinkcoke" and a null-terminator).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> but I read somewhere else that I couldnt do test[i] == test2[i] in C.

That would be really painful to compare character-by-character like that. As you want to compare two character arrays (strings) here, you should use `strcmp` instead:

```
if( strcmp(test, test2) == 0)
{
    printf("equal");
}
```

Edit:

- There is no need to specify the size when you initialise the character arrays. This would be better:

  `char test[] = "idrinkcoke";`
  `char test2[] = "idrinknote";`
- It'd also be better if you use `strncmp` - which is safer in general (if a character array happens to be NOT NULL-terminated).

  `if(strncmp(test, test2, sizeof(test)) == 0)`

Comment: I see. I didn't know this before. Thank you.

Comment: Don't you miss the "n" in your strncmp sample code?

Comment: @Habib yes I did, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the C library function `strcmp`

Like this:

`if strcmp(test, test2) == 0`

From the [documentation on strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

> Compares the C string str1 to the C string str2.
>
> This function starts comparing the first character of each string. If
>   they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs
>   until the characters differ or until a terminating null-character is
>   reached.
>
> This function performs a binary comparison of the characters. For a
>   function that takes into account locale-specific rules, see strcoll.

and on the return value:

> returns 0 if the contents of both strings are equal

Comment: I would very much like to share some personal experiences from both company as well as azubi-side regarding your workplace question, but I can't do that on q/a. If you're interested in talking, please drop me an email. :)